# How to access host http server in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

If http server is running on host system and and http client want to run inside pod. Is it possible to connect with host system server using host ip address.NodePort service is applicable for connecting for host http server?

Comment: Did you try connecting using the host ip address? Did it work or not?

Comment: Host ip inside pod? Because i need to run server on host system.with host ip i tried inside pod.but it is not able to bind.i am running client inside

Comment: Hello. Do I understand correctly that you want to connect from your pod (client) to the application (server) sitting on the same host? Is this application running directly on host or is it in a pod? Could you show what have you tried?  `NodePort` service would be used if you've wanted to connect to your **pods** and not an application deployed directly on your host.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure host is listening on all interfaces and not just `localhost`. Try connecting to service from another machine to test first, not pod. From the network's point of view, those are two separate machines. See the following for an example:

Test from OSX:

```bash
$ HOST_IP=$(ifconfig | grep en0 -A 5 | grep 'inet ' | cut -d' ' -f2)
$ brew install nginx
$ nginx
$ curl -I $HOST_IP:8080 2>/dev/null | head -n 1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

$ docker run -ti --rm centos curl -I $HOST_IP:8080 2>/dev/null | head -n 1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```